# Alltt inside mdframed longtable

Tags: tables, mdframed

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have text material which is to be put in verbatim form. This material also has some mathematics, so I am using the `alltt` package. This text needs to be in a single column table, which should be framed, for which I am using the `mdframed` package.

The MWE is as below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{alltt}
\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}
\caption{This is the caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces a table which goes beyond the current page. What is needed is that the table overflows with the outer frame to the next page. I tried to use the `longtable` but it seems `alltt` does not like it.

Any other method of achieving this `alltt` inside a boxed table which can flow across pages would also be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is a float and it won't break across pages. And if you use a longtable, it too can't break across the pages inside the same row (and you have only one row). What to do? Don't use them. If you need a caption use `\captionof{table}{caption...}` from either `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt,capt-of}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\captionof{table}{This is the caption}
\egroup
\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip]
\begin{alltt}
\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
\end{alltt}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On ther other hand, there is also `tcolorbox` that offer lot more. Here is an example for your case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt,capt-of}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}


\begin{document}
%\begin{table}
\bgroup
\captionof{table}{This is the caption}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,%light-gray,  
    breakable,sharpish corners
    ]
\begin{alltt}
\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
        \textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();\textbf{OOS()}
begin
preprocess the image \emph{m}.
        data\_normalize(\emph{data}, \emph{method});
        kmeans(data, n);
        kmedoid(data, n);
        fcmeans(data, n);
        validity(result, data, param);
        object();
\end{alltt}
\end{tcolorbox}
\egroup


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine as required. But if I place the `captionof` at the beginning (which I want) instead of the end (like in the example above), it doesn't work properly. The caption remains on one page while the `mdframed` is moved to the next without breaking. Any workaround for placing the caption at the start rather than at the end?

Comment: I get the following error while running the above code                                                      ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `many' for package `tcolorbox'.

...                                                  
l.755 \ProcessOptions*

Also after letting this pass I get few more errors! 

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/enhanced jigsaw' and I am 
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/breakable' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

The resulting frame does not break across pages.

Comment: @Damitr Use `\usepackage{tcolorbox} \tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}` instead of `\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} ` (see the edited answer). If this doesn't work, you have to update your `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The first error has gone with the changes in the preamble. But the remaining two still persist. I remove the `enhanced jigsaw` and `sharpish corners` options and it woks fine now. Thanks for the help.